# No module named 'Pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, import, site-packages

this is the following code which i was try to run:

```
dict = {"country": ["Brazil", "Russia", "India", "China", "South Africa"],
       "capital": ["Brasilia", "Moscow", "New Dehli", "Beijing", "Pretoria"],
       "area": [8.516, 17.10, 3.286, 9.597, 1.221],
       "population": [200.4, 143.5, 1252, 1357, 52.98] }

# import pandas as pd
import Pandas as pd
f=pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(f)
```

but unfortunately this showed up on VS code terminal, i try to found the solution but didnt able to get it with proper answer. Please I will love to hear your opinion .

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Python/Learn Python/Pandas basics/Pdf.py", line 7, in <module>
    import Pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pandas'*
```

Comment: `pandas` not `Pandas` (capitalization matters)

Comment: Also do not name your variable `dict` as you are now shadowing the name of the type.

Answer (score 2):

The pandas module name is all lower case. Try `import pandas as pd` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Python is case sensitive. Capital alphabet will mean different.
You have to mention all in small case.
import pandas as pd